# Most efficient way to replace HTML special entities to custom string

Tags: c#, string

I want to replace [ALL HTML special entities](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php) like `&gt; &lt;` to custom string.

Lets say i have following string:

```
string str = "<div>&gt;hello&lt;</div>";
```

and method:
`Method(string str, string replaceStr)`

After calling `Method(str, ":)")` result should be

```
<div>:)hello:)</div>
```

The problem is there are too many of special characters and I'm wondering what is the be most efficient way to accomplish this?

EDIT:

String.Replace will not do my work and using Regex for parsing HTML is not really good approach.

By dislikes on this quetion there propably isn't any clean solution therefore I decided go for following algorithm:

1. create txt file with valid HTML special characters (like
   `&para;`)
2. parse file into array of string
3. Thanks to HtmLAgilityPack parse HTML and get raw text and replace all entities.

I know that this is not really effective for big html string but it should do the work for now.

Comment: `String.Replace()` looks promising.

Comment: I meant all these entities. My mistake. I've edited question.

Comment: `Regex.Replace(str, @"&\p{L}+;", ":)")`? This might overfire. You'd need to evaluate if the matched text is a real entity.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
        string str = "<div>&gt;hello&lt;</div>";
        string output = Regex.Replace(str, "&gt;|&lt;", ":)");
```

---

You can also use HtmlDecode

```
        string str = "<div>&gt;hello&lt;</div>";
        string output = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(str);
```

Comment: Don't use the regex, the WebUtility is the correct answer here

Comment: Or HttpUtility.HtmlDecode

Comment: @Yanga - The `WebUtility` saved my life